# values are not changing in a table inside foreach function jquery

Tags: jquery

In my table the value of `CalculatedRate` is updating with last value of for each function. If you see console there are three different values but it's taking the last value and updating the same value for all three rows.

```js
  var calcObject = {
    run: function(flag) {
      var target_total = $('.TargetRate').val();
      var current_rate_total = $('.CurrentRateTotal').text();
      calcObject.difference = (parseFloat(current_rate_total) - parseFloat(target_total));
      var profit_total = 0;
      $("table").each(function() {
        $(this).find(".CurrentRate").each(function() {
          var werate = $(this).data('rate');
          var cost = $(this).data('cost');
          var profit = $(this).data('profit');

          calcObject.minsales = ((parseFloat(cost) * (parseFloat(profit))) / 100);
          calcObject.profit = (parseFloat(werate) - parseFloat(calcObject.minsales));

          calcObject.per_of_total = ((100 / (61.99)) * (parseFloat(calcObject.profit)));

          calcObject.per_of_diff = ((parseFloat(calcObject.difference) * (parseFloat(calcObject.per_of_total))) / 100);

          if (parseFloat(calcObject.per_of_diff) < parseFloat(calcObject.profit)) {

            calcObject.cal_rate = (parseFloat(werate) - parseFloat(calcObject.per_of_diff));

          } else if (parseFloat(calcObject.per_of_diff) > parseFloat(calcObject.profit)) {

            calcObject.cal_rate = (parseFloat(werate) - parseFloat(calcObject.profit));
          }
          console.log(calcObject.cal_rate);

          $('.CalculatedRate').text(parseFloat(calcObject.cal_rate).toFixed(2));
        });
      });
      var calTotal = 0;
      $(".CalculatedRate").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).text();
        if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
          calTotal += parseFloat(value);
        }
      });
      $('.CalculatedRateTotal').html(parseFloat(calTotal).toFixed(2));
    }
  };
  $(function() {

    $(document).on('change', '.TargetRate', function() {
      calcObject.run(0);
    });
    $(document).on('change', '.CurrentRate', function() {
      calcObject.run(0);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade in" id="dayRateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: block; padding-right: 15px;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="priceDataAlgorithm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Day Rate Calculator</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4>Please enter your target day rate:</h4>

          <input type="text" class="form-control TargetRate" name="">
          <p>
            &nbsp;
          </p>
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Current Rate</th>
                <th>Calculated Rate</th>
                <th>Overwrite Rate</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Mini Planer
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" data-cost="120" data-profit="120" class="CurrentRate" data-rate="180"> 180

                </td>
                <td><span class="CalculatedRate"></span></td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control OverwriteRate" name="">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Planer Operator
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" data-cost="156" data-profit="130" class="CurrentRate" data-rate="220"> 220

                </td>
                <td><span class="CalculatedRate"></span></td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control OverwriteRate" name="">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Banksman
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" data-cost="110" data-profit="120" class="CurrentRate" data-rate="140"> 140

                </td>
                <td><span class="CalculatedRate"></span></td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control OverwriteRate" name="">
                </td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th><span class="CurrentRateTotal">540</span></th>
                <th><span class="CalculatedRateTotal"></span></th>
                <th>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="">
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions, Please! Here is the [jsfiddledemo](https://jsfiddle.net/fh856nyL/32/)

Console is not visible in this snippet please refer fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem where it is.

```
$('.CalculatedRate').text(parseFloat(calcObject.cal_rate).toFixed(2));
```

In the above line it could not able find the nearest `td` tag for this.so It should the below

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(2) .CalculatedRate").text(parseFloat(calcObject.cal_rate).toFixed(2));
```

Then its started working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) you should use function parameters instead of $this in a loop. E.g.:

```
$(this).find(".CurrentRate").each(function() {
var werate = $(this).data('rate');
```

should be

```
$(this).find(".CurrentRate").each(function(key,item) {
var werate = item.data('rate');
```